# W1035 Return value of function 'MemFind' might be undefined

Tags: delphi

Программа скомпилирована. Но получаю это предупреждение:

```
 W1035 Return value of function 'MemFind' might be undefined
```

Предупреждение вылетает в этой части кода:

```
function MemFind(mp: pbyte; ml: integer; vp: pbyte; vl: integer): pbyte;
var
  lim: pbyte;
  first: byte;
begin
  if (vl < 1) or (ml < vl) then
  begin
    result := nil;
    exit;
  end;
  if vl = 1 then
    result := MemFind(mp, vp^, ml)
  else
  begin
    lim := PByte(PAnsiChar(mp) + (ml - vl));
    first := vp^;
    while cardinal(mp) < cardinal(lim) do
    begin
      result := MemFind(mp, first, cardinal(lim) - cardinal(mp) + 1);
      if (result = nil) or CompareMem(PAnsiChar(result) + 1, PAnsiChar(vp) + 1, vl - 1) then
        exit;
      mp := pbyte(PAnsiChar(result) + 1);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Предупреждение указывает на  последнюю строку end;
Эта программа была переведена с Delphi 7 на Delphi 10.2!
Почему возвращаемое значение функции «MemFind» может быть не определено?!

Comment: Потому что если `vl > 1` и `cardinal(mp) >= cardinal(lim)` то Result будет не инициализирован.

Comment: @kami: то ли меня глючит, или я все правильно написал? И у вас написан комент обратный моему коду?

Comment: я написал, при каких входящих условиях вы получите мусор в результате этой функции. Компилятор предупреждает правильно. Входим в последнюю ветку условия (в else) и если цикл while ни разу не выполнится - на выходе будет неизвестно что.

Comment: в конце функции напишите `result := nil` и предупреждение исчезнет. ну или такое проще наоборот вначале самом писать.

Comment: @teran: я бы все таки хотел бы использовать данную функцию.

Comment: так и используйте, никто ж не запрещает. Вам объяснили, почему компилятор ругается (не запрещая ничего при этом, заметьте). Что с этим делать дальше - зависит от вас. Точнее - от того, как вы видите работу этой функции.

Comment: либо модифицируйте код функции, либо игнорируйте это предупреждение. третьего варианта здесь нет.

Comment: Спасибо большое за пояснение проблемы.

Comment: @teran  result := nil нужно писать *в начале*. Если написать в конце, то результат всегда будет nil.

Comment: @VladChapl вы на код посмотрите, там во всех иф-ах `exit`-натыканы. Единственная ветка на которую компилятор тут ругается и есть в конце функции. Но в общем случае, проще писать вначале, да, и я об этом в своем комментарии выше также написал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Компилятор предупреждает вас правильно:

```
function MemFind(mp: pbyte; ml: integer; vp: pbyte; vl: integer): pbyte;
begin
  ..
  begin
    ..
    // <--
    while cardinal(mp) < cardinal(lim) do
    begin
      result := ..
    end;
  end;
end;
```

А что будет если `vl > 1` и `cardinal(mp) >= cardinal(lim)` - мы не зайдем в while .. Результат не будет присвоен.